# Run time for curl command

Tags: bash, shell, networking, curl

I have a file of domain names (~9000 urls). I am trying to determine the time taken to execute a successful curl request for all the urls.

```
#!/bin/bash

#read lines from file. 
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

#Start execution time. 
start=`date +%s.%N`

curl -k -L $line

if (("$?" != "7")) || (("$?" != "6")) ||(("$?" != "35")) ; then  

#If curl request is not one of these [error codes][1] then end execution time
    end=`date +%s.%N`
fi
runtime=$( echo "$end - $start" | bc -l ) >> throughput.txt

#Can do an average on the file later. 


done < urls.txt
```

For some reason the loop stops after reading the first url. Can someone please help me correctly run the script.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of your script to get a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: It stop after the the curl command curl -k -L $line

Comment: Maybe post the output to a pastebin and include link here

Comment: You can also use time command to measure duration of you curl command, like 'time curl -k -L $line'. You can also specify output format for time command.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LZmNevYa

Comment: You might want to take a look at `curl`s `--write-out` option. `time_total` will report *the total time, in seconds, that the full operation lasted. The time will be displayed with millisecond resolution.*

Comment: @AbhimanyuKhanna That error you posted in pastebin, occurs becaus you try curl https in site which does not have https. Try it with http and it will succeed without errors.